# ASP.net C# multiple web applications - One File Upload directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I don't know why this is becoming such a hard concept for me to grasp. I'm struggling with the following issue and any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have two ASP.net MVC 4 applications running C#. They are two sepereate applications one for the public facing site and the other for our admin side. The reason we separated the two is because they are two completely separate designs and code bases and it will be easier to manage.

The two applications are connected to one SQL Server Database instance.

We have a file upload functionallity on each site and I'm trying to figure out a way to store the file uploads in one common directory for both sites.

The issue is that when a file gets uploaded we store the image location in the database.

> /Uploads/filename.png

We do this using the following function.

> Server.MapPath("~" + TempImage.ThumbnailLocation.Replace("TempUploads/", "")));

**How can I save the files from both sites to the same directory on the server so I can keep all my image paths the same in the database?**

The other issues that I need to be able to call, from both applications, the following to delete an image.

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Path)))
{
     System.IO.File.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Path));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a virtual directory in each of your applications. The virtual directory will point to a single physical path. So you can upload and delete file from the same physical directory on both sites.

Comment: Thanks Alexandr, can I still use Server.MapPath with a virtual directory in order to save and delete from that folder?

Comment: Yep, Server.MapPath knows how to map virual directory to a physical one

Answer (score 1):

I usually use BLOB storage, which is very cheap either from [Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or [Microsoft](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/) (and many other providers)

This approach is better because:

- It reduces the risk of data loss in case of hardware failure on your single server machine
- Your page loads faster since assets are loaded from a CDN
- You can reuse the files from any application since they're all in the cloud

Here's a couple of tutorials to get started on azure:

- http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/
- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/How-To-Use-Azure-Blob-16882fe2

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to use [Virtual Directories](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis#Virtual) - in IIS, both sites can be configured as having a "/Uploads/" virtual directory and they can both be mapped to the same location on the hard drive.